# Ansible synchronize mode permissions

Tags: ansible, rsync

I'm using an Ansible playbook to copy files between my host and a server. The thing is, I have to run the script repeatedly in order to upload some updates. At the beginning I was using the "copy" module of Ansible, but to improve performance of the synchronizing of files and directories, I've now switched to use the "synchronize" module. That way I can ensure Ansible uses rsync instead of sftp or scp.

With the "copy" module, I was able to specify the file's mode in the destination host by adding the mode option (e.g. `mode=644`). I want to do that using synchronize, but it only has the `perms` option that accepts yes or no as values.

Is there a way to specify the file's mode using "synchronize", without having to inherit it?

Thx!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally I solved it using `rsync_opts`

```
- name: sync file
  synchronize:
    src: file.py
    dest: /home/myuser/file.py
    rsync_opts:
      - "--chmod=F644"
```